How to extract data from my JSON file to display on tkinter GUI
I am creating a client/server program for an assignment, the goal is to send inputs from the client program to the server program, the server program then takes said inputs and uses this to interrogate OHM (Open Hardware Monitor) for overall CPU temp, CPU load, each CPU core temp and then send these back to the client which will then write them to a JSON file and then use the file to get the required data and display it on a tkinter GUI.
I have every part of my programs working as expected except I just cannot seem to pull the information from my JSON file and I just cannot see where I am going wrong.
Server program :
import queue
import socket
import threading
import time
import wmi
import json
import pythoncom

queue_1 = queue.Queue(maxsize=50)  # queue for user instructions
queue_2 = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)  # queue for received data --> write to json


class ReceiveData(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("ReceiveData thread initialised")
        # define port and IP for receiving data
        UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
        UDP_PORT = 9994
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.settimeout(60)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not queue_1.full():
                try:
                    data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(4096)  # buffer is 1024 bytes
                    # print(f"received {data}")
                    data = data.decode("utf-8")
                    queue_1.put(data)
                    # print("received data put in queue")
                except socket.timeout:
                    print("didn't receive any data (ReceiveData)")
                    self.sock.close()


class HardwareMonitor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("HWM Thread initialised")
        self.hwmon = None
        self.sensors = None
        self.instruction = None
        self.cpu_temps = None
        self.sens_name = None
        self.current_time = None
        self.sens_type = None
        self.cpu_load = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.instruction = queue_1.get()
                print("took information off of queue1")
                # sensor: "CPU Package"
                # value: "Temperature"

                pythoncom.CoInitialize()
                self.hwmon = wmi.WMI(namespace=r"root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
                self.sensors = self.hwmon.Sensor()

                for sensor in self.sensors:
                    if sensor.SensorType == u'Temperature' and sensor.Name == "CPU Package":
                        self.cpu_temps = sensor.value
                        self.sens_name = sensor.Name
                        self.sens_type = sensor.SensorType
                        self.current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
                        # print(f"CPU is {self.cpu_temps}°C on {self.sens_name} the time of read {self.current_time}")

                    if sensor.SensorType == u'Load' and sensor.Name == "CPU Total":
                        self.cpu_load = sensor.value
                        self.sens_name = sensor.Name
                        self.sens_type = sensor.SensorType
                        self.current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
                        # print(f"CPU load is {self.cpu_load}% on {self.sens_name} time of read {self.current_time}")

                        load_dict = {
                            "Name": self.sens_name,
                            "Sensor Type": self.sens_type,
                            "Value": self.cpu_temps
                        }

                        json_str = json.dumps(load_dict)

                        print(json_str)

                        queue_2.put(json_str)
                        print("data put in queue2")
            except:
                pass


class SendData(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("SendData thread initialised")
        self.send = True
        self.UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
        self.UDP_PORT = 9997
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.run()
        # print("Getting here")

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        while True:
            if not queue_2.empty():
                q_data = queue_2.get()
                # print(type(q_data))
                print("got information from queue2")
                s_data = json.dumps(q_data)
                # print("I just got to here")
                print(f"sending data - {s_data}")
                self.sock.sendto(bytes(str(s_data), "utf-8"), (self.UDP_IP, self.UDP_PORT))
                time.sleep(1)
            elif queue_2.empty():
                print("queue2 was empty")
                break


def main():
    receiver = ReceiveData()
    receiver.start()

    hardware = HardwareMonitor()
    hardware.start()

    sender = SendData()
    sender.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Client program
import queue
import socket
import threading
import json
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk

queue_1 = queue.Queue(maxsize=1)  # queue for user instructions
queue_2 = queue.Queue(maxsize=50)  # queue for received data --> write to json


class JSONWriter:
    def __init__(self, signal):
        self.signal = signal
        print("JSON Writer started")
        # self.num_records = num_records
        # self.time_spacing = time_spacing

    def write(self, record):
        with open(self.signal, 'a') as outfile:
            json_data = json.dumps(record) + '\n'
            parsed = json.loads(json_data)

            json.dump(parsed, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True))


class SendInstructions(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("Sender thread started")
        self.UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
        self.UDP_PORT = 9994
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.settimeout(20)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

    def run(self):
        try:
            while True:
                data = queue_1.get()
                # print(data)
                data = json.dumps(data)
                self.sock.sendto(bytes(str(data), "utf-8"), (self.UDP_IP, self.UDP_PORT))
                # print("request sent to server")
        except socket.timeout:
            print("didn't receive any data (ReceiveData)")
            self.sock.close()
            print("receive socket closed")


class ReceiveData(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("receiving started")
        # print("Receiver thread started")
        # define port and IP for receiving data
        UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
        UDP_PORT = 9997
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(4096)  # buffer is 1024 bytes
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            print(f"received {data}")
            queue_2.put(data)


class Export(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("Export thread started")

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                print("Export loop started")
                data = queue_2.get()
                with open("Export.json", 'a') as temps:
                    temps_str = json.dumps(data,
                                           indent=4, sort_keys=True,
                                           ensure_ascii=False)
                    print(f"exporting {temps_str}")

                    temps.write(temps_str)
                    temps.write("\n")
            except QueueEmptyError:
                print("Queue 2 was empty")
                pass


class ClientGUI(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, master):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print("tkinter thread booted")
        master.title("Client GUI")
        master.geometry('600x600')

        self.txt_cpu = Text(master, height=2, width=51)
        self.txt_cpu.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        self.txt_cpu.delete("1.0", END)
        self.txt_cpu.after(1000, self.update_text())

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.pack()

    def update_text(self):
        print("update text running")
        try:
            dictionary = self.load_dict()
            # print(dictionary)
            self.txt_cpu.delete("1.0", tk.END)
            self.txt_cpu.after(1000, self.update_text())
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Export.txt not found.")
            self.txt_cpu.after(1000, self.update_text())

    def load_dict(self):
        with open('Export.json', 'r') as f:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
            last_line = lines[-1]
            print(last_line)

    def run(self):
        print("Record print started")
        num_records = 100
        timespacing_seconds = 1

        current_time = time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
        filename_json = current_time + "_" + str(timespacing_seconds) + ".json"
        control_writer = JSONWriter(filename_json)

        for i in range(1, num_records):
            raw_data = i

            control_writer.write(raw_data)

            time.sleep(timespacing_seconds)

            queue_1.put(raw_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sender = SendInstructions()
    receiver = ReceiveData()
    export = Export()

    sender.start()
    receiver.start()
    export.start()

root = Tk()
client_gui = ClientGUI(root)
client_gui.start()
root.mainloop()

Example Export.json file
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 38.875}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 39.5}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 39.75}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 39.75}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 39.625}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 40.0}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 40.0}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 40.0}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 39.75}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 39.875}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 39.625}\""
"\"{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"CPU Total\\\", \\\"Sensor Type\\\": \\\"Load\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 39.75}\""

I have tried lots of different things, tried changing how I send the dictionary etc, just nothing seems to be working.

SO isn't a debugging service.  Focus on one problem that you don't understand, make a [mcve] (read this!) and document the inputs, expected vs. received outputs, and any error messages.  It looks like the Export.json isn't written correctly, for one problem.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

It seems it sends all as single string instead of sending it as dictionary. I don't understand why you use so many dumps and loads in write() - maybe all this makes this problem. Why not use directly json.dump(record, ...) instead of json.dump(parsed, ...)

BTW: if you append data to existing JSON file then you creates incorrect file - or you create file called multi-JSON

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

I can't test it but I think I see problem - you use dumps() two times and this gives strange string.
Server runs dumps() when it puts data in queue
and later when it gets data from queue then it runs again dumps()
but it should use loads() to convert string back to dictionary (and later use dumps() to send it)
or it should send string which it get from queue without using dumps
load_dict = {

    "Name": self.sens_name,
    "Sensor Type": self.sens_type,
    "Value": self.cpu_temps
}

json_str = json.dumps(load_dict)   # <--- first `dumps`

print(json_str)

queue_2.put(json_str)
print("data put in queue2")

if not queue_2.empty():
    q_data = queue_2.get()
    # print(type(q_data))
    print("got information from queue2")

    s_data = json.dumps(q_data)   # <--- second `dumps`

    # print("I just got to here")
    print(f"sending data - {s_data}")
    self.sock.sendto(bytes(str(s_data), "utf-8"), (self.UDP_IP, self.UDP_PORT))

You should send q_data instead of s_data because q_data is already json_str

And I think you may have  similar problem in Client. It gets json str from socket but it uses dumps again before putting to queue, and later after getting it from queue it runs again dumps.

Frankly, I lost in all these dumps in code.
